# C# Winforms designer crashes visual studio when opening the designer window

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been dealing with this problem for awhile now and haven't managed to progress any further for the past few hours so I thought I'll ask here. When I'm opening the designer window in winforms I get to this [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skh2g.png). Which after about 5 to 10 seconds freezes my Visual Studio and then crashes and reopens automatically. When this happens I can go to my event viewer and find the following two error messages

Level Error:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          10/10/2021 16.19.22
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      w10-virt-aca.judex.net
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 16.11.31727.386, time stamp: 0x615257fa
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1202, time stamp: 0x448a4f5d
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0012b5b2
Faulting process id: 0x4314
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7bde1394d2a09
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 2d116bf6-eee2-471d-b458-5199c1cf7c30
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-10-10T14:19:22.2983088Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31817</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>w10-virt-aca.judex.net</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>16.11.31727.386</Data>
    <Data>615257fa</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>10.0.19041.1202</Data>
    <Data>448a4f5d</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0012b5b2</Data>
    <Data>4314</Data>
    <Data>01d7bde1394d2a09</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>2d116bf6-eee2-471d-b458-5199c1cf7c30</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Level Information:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          10/10/2021 16.20.48
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      w10-virt-aca.judex.net
Description:
Fault bucket 125730739576, type 5
Event Name: PerfWatsonVS12Data
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: PerfWatsonTcdb
P2: 0
P3: 0
P4: 0
P5: 0
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Users\aca\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTelem.Out\202110101420_D16.11_16.11.31727.386_8460_7747fac7-2021-4e3a-822b-736e4bab2863.tcdb
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2A96.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AB7.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AC7.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AF7.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_PerfWatsonTcdb_688f135dd185f2a8133a474a2518efc6ce6cc4a_00000000_c8109fff-f54e-4b17-ba40-d36334af35e8

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c8109fff-f54e-4b17-ba40-d36334af35e8
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: fb30d2b9a7acf0305d4da51668259751
Cab Guid: 0
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-10-10T14:20:48.9503861Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31819</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>w10-virt-aca.judex.net</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>125730739576</Data>
    <Data>5</Data>
    <Data>PerfWatsonVS12Data</Data>
    <Data>Not available</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>PerfWatsonTcdb</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
\\?\C:\Users\aca\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTelem.Out\202110101420_D16.11_16.11.31727.386_8460_7747fac7-2021-4e3a-822b-736e4bab2863.tcdb
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2A96.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AB7.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AC7.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER2AF7.tmp.txt</Data>
    <Data>\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_PerfWatsonTcdb_688f135dd185f2a8133a474a2518efc6ce6cc4a_00000000_c8109fff-f54e-4b17-ba40-d36334af35e8</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>c8109fff-f54e-4b17-ba40-d36334af35e8</Data>
    <Data>268435456</Data>
    <Data>fb30d2b9a7acf0305d4da51668259751</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Does anyone have the sligtest idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The error message explains that your form during it's instantiation process (in constructor or somewhere called from there) is trying to access a `ActionLogService.IActionLogService` which is not available. If you click on `Show Call Stack` link you will see where is that code line.

I would open the code file without designer support, go to that line and change it like this:

```
if (!this.DesignMode) 
{
   // here comes the original ActionLogService lines
}
else
{
   // here optionally could be something mocking the ActionLogService during design time
}
```

E.g. I have a dialog with a dynamic list of actually available choices calculated and returned by a webservice call. During design time I do not want the webservice to be available but wanted to see some dummy values instead in the list. Here it is:

```
List<string> availableChoices;
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
   availableChoices = GetAvailableChoicesFromWebserviceCall();
}
else
{
   availableChoices = new List<string>() { "dummyDesignTimeOption1", "dummyDesignTimeOption2" };
}
```